# redux-form Dinamically inject objects into FieldArray `field` property

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

What I am trying to accomplish is a dynamic FieldArray similar to the one in the [redux form example](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/fieldArrays/) but the difference is that every object I am adding to the list already has all properties (which i have to display) but one that I need to calculate from other two of them.

Take a look at this example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const renderSelect = (products) => (
  <div>
    <label>Select Product to Add</label>
    <div>
      <Field name="products" component="select">
        <option></option>
        {products.map(p => <option value={p.id}>{p.name}</option>)}
      </Field>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const renderCompetences = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Competence</button>
        {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div> */}
      <ul>
        {fields.map((competence, index) =>
                    <li key={index}>
                      <h4>Competence #{index + 1}</h4>
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.singlePrice`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderField}
                        label="Single Price"/>
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.standardQuantity`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderField}
                        label="Standard Quantity"/>
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.totalPrice`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderField}
                        label="Total Price"/>

                      <button 
                        type="button" 
                        onClick={() => fields.remove(index)} 
                        style={{color: 'red'}}
                        >
                        ✘
                      </button>
                    </li>
                   )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const FieldArraysForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, products, productsValue } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="recipientName" type="text" component={renderField} label="Recipient Name"/>
      <FieldArray name="competences" component={renderCompetences} />
      {renderSelect(products)}
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

const selector = formValueSelector('fieldArrays');

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const productsValue = selector(state, 'products');
  return { productsValue };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'fieldArrays'
  })
)(FieldArraysForm);
```

I should display the products I selected form the select in my unordered list and every time I select a new object I should add it to the list.

Here you can see an example of the products array:

```
const products = [
  { id: '0', name: 'Product One', singlePrice: 101, standardQuantity: 1},
  { id: '1', name: 'Product Two', singlePrice: 39, standardQuantity: 6},
  { id: '2', name: 'Product Three', singlePrice: 85, standardQuantity: 4},
  { id: '3', name: 'Product Four', singlePrice: 1, standardQuantity: 20}
];
```

**Here is a working example to test some solutions:**
https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kecgj77Gbxo_4am3WS1

Thank you so much for any help you can give!

Comment: Why aren't you using `productsValue` anywhere? I'm not understand what that value is used for.

Comment: I brought it up because i thought it could be useful but after a few tries... i don't know if it's so useful

Comment: @ErikR. any news about this? Is my issue clear? any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: Webpackbin isn't working for me. :-( It runs, but doesn't let me select other files or edit the existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i came up with:

```
import React from 'react'
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const renderCalcField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error }, calc }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} value={calc()} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const renderCompetences = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }, products, productSelectValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((competence, index) =>
                    <li key={index}>
                      <h4>Competence #{index + 1}</h4>
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.singlePrice`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderField}
                        label="Single Price"
                        onChange={() => {
                          const current = fields.get(index);
                          current.totalPrice = current.singlePrice * current.standardQuantity;
                          fields.remove(index);
                          fields.insert(index, current);
                        }}
                        />
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.standardQuantity`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderField}
                        label="Standard Quantity"
                        />
                      <Field
                        name={`${competence}.totalPrice`}
                        type="number"
                        component={renderCalcField}
                        props={{calc: () => {
                          const current = fields.get(index);
                          return current.singlePrice * current.standardQuantity;
                        }}}
                        label="Total Price"
                        />

                      <button 
                        type="button" 
                        onClick={() => fields.remove(index)} 
                        style={{color: 'red'}}
                        >
                        ✘
                      </button>
                    </li>
                   )}
      </ul>
      <div>
        <Field name="productSelect" component="select">
          <option>Select product</option>
          {products.map(p => <option value={p.id}>{p.name}</option>)}
        </Field>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => {
            const selectedProduct = products.find(p => p.id === productSelectValue);
            fields.push(selectedProduct);
          }}>Add</button>
        {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const FieldArraysForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, products, productSelectValue } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="recipientName" type="text" component={renderField} label="Recipient Name"/>
      <FieldArray name="competences" component={renderCompetences} props={{products, productSelectValue}}/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

const selector = formValueSelector('fieldArrays');

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const productSelectValue = selector(state, 'productSelect');
  return { productSelectValue };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'fieldArrays'
  })
)(FieldArraysForm);
```

[working here on webpackbin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KgsSdR5Bf9rEEjFoQgz) (sometimes it has loading problems but it does not depend on my example)